# Collapse multiple rows into a single row based upon a break condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple sounding requirement that has had me stumped for a day or so now, so its time to seek help from the experts.

My requirement is to simply roll-up multiple rows into a single row based upon a break condition - when any of these columns change Employee ID, Allowance Plan, Allowance Amount or To Date, then the row is to be kept, if that makes sense.

An example source data set is shown below:

[image]

and the target data after collapsing the rows should look like this:

[image]

As you can see I don't need any type of running totals calculating I just need to collapse the rows into a single record per from date/to date combination.

So far I have tried the following SQL using a GROUP BY and MIN function

```
select [Employee ID], [Allowance Plan], 
       min([From Date]), max([To Date]), [Allowance Amount] 
from   [dbo].[#AllowInfo] 
group by [Employee ID], [Allowance Plan], [Allowance Amount]
```

but that just gives me a single row and does not take into account the break condition.

what do I need to do so that the records are rolled-up (correct me if that is not the right terminology) correctly taking into account the break condition?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post sample data as text not images.

Comment: You may have unstated requirements about partitioning and order of the rows, which is one reason it's difficult to find the right SQL logic.  It's possible you could use LAG (a window function) to identify these "break conditions" and then use a running count of the break conditions found to decide how to group the rows.  But to do that properly, you need to more clearly state the requirement.

Comment: Screen shots are pretty to look at but greatly reduce your chances of getting an answer with a working query, because we can't copy text or query images.  So you're left waiting for someone to spot the problem visually or that feels generous enough to retype out all that sample data ... Better to post it as text, preferably in the form of a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/ or https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: I might have some ideas how to do this, but I am not going to type over all your data from an image to test it, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments I found them very constructive and will certainly help with submitting any future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your test data does not really exercise the algo that well -  e.g. you only have one employee, one plan. Also, as you described it, you would end up with 4 rows as there is a change of todate between 7->8, 8->9, 9->10 and 10->11.

But I can see what you are trying to do, so this should at least get you on the right track, and returns the expected 3 rows. I have taken the end of a group to be where either employee/plan/amount has changed, or where todate is not null (or where we reach the end of the data)

```
CREATE TABLE #data
(
    RowID INT,
    EmployeeID INT,
    AllowancePlan VARCHAR(30),
    FromDate DATE, 
    ToDate DATE,
    AllowanceAmount DECIMAL(12,2)
);

INSERT INTO #data(RowID, EmployeeID, AllowancePlan, FromDate, ToDate, AllowanceAmount)
VALUES
(1,200690,'CarAllowance','30/03/2017', NULL, 1000.0),
(2,200690,'CarAllowance','01/08/2017', NULL, 1000.0),
(6,200690,'CarAllowance','23/04/2018', NULL, 1000.0),
(7,200690,'CarAllowance','30/03/2018', NULL, 1000.0),
(8,200690,'CarAllowance','21/06/2018', '01/04/2019', 1000.0),
(9,200690,'CarAllowance','04/11/2021', NULL, 1000.0),
(10,200690,'CarAllowance','30/03/2017', '13/05/2022', 1000.0),
(11,200690,'CarAllowance','14/05/2022', NULL, 850.0);

-- find where the break points are
WITH chg AS 
(
    SELECT *, 
        CASE WHEN LAG(EmployeeID, 1, -1) OVER(ORDER BY RowID) != EmployeeID
               OR LAG(AllowancePlan, 1, 'X') OVER(ORDER BY RowID) != AllowancePlan  
               OR LAG(AllowanceAmount, 1, -1) OVER(ORDER BY RowID) != AllowanceAmount
               OR LAG(ToDate, 1) OVER(ORDER BY RowID) IS NOT NULL
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NewGroup
    FROM #data   
), 
-- count the number of break points as we go to group the related rows
grp AS
(
    SELECT chg.*,
        ISNULL(
            SUM(NewGroup) 
                OVER (ORDER BY RowID 
                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),
              0) AS grpNum
    FROM chg
) 
SELECT  MIN(grp.RowID) AS RowID, 
        MAX(grp.EmployeeID) AS EmployeeID,      
        MAX(grp.AllowancePlan) AS AllowancePlan,
        MIN(grp.FromDate) AS FromDate, 
        MAX(grp.ToDate) AS ToDate,  
        MAX(grp.AllowanceAmount) AS AllowanceAmount
FROM grp
GROUP BY grpNum
```

Comment: Thank you @James Casey for the solution it worked a treat!

Answer (score 1):

one way is to get all rows the last todate, and then group on that

```
select min(t.RowID) as RowID,
       t.EmployeeID,
       min(t.AllowancePlan) as AllowancePlan,
       min(t.FromDate) as FromDate,
       max(t.ToDate) as ToDate,
       min(t.AllowanceAmount) as AllowanceAmount
from   ( select t.RowID,
                t.EmployeeID,
                t.FromDate,
                t.AllowancePlan,
                t.AllowanceAmount,
                case when t.ToDate is null then ( select top 1 t2.ToDate 
                                                  from   test t2
                                                  where  t2.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
                                                  and    t2.ToDate is not null
                                                  and    t2.FromDate > t.FromDate -- t2.RowID > t.RowID
                                                  order by t2.RowID, t2.FromDate 
                                                )
                     else t.ToDate
                end as todate     
         from   test t
       ) t

group by t.EmployeeID, t.ToDate
order by t.EmployeeID, min(t.RowID)
```

See and test yourself [in this DBFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/88d30/4)

the result is

| RowID | EmployeeID | AllowancePlan | FromDate | ToDate | AllowanceAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200690 | CarAllowance | 2017-03-30 | 2019-04-01 | 1000 |
| 9 | 200690 | CarAllowance | 2021-11-04 | 2022-05-13 | 1000 |
| 11 | 200690 | CarAllowance | 2022-05-14 | (null) | 850 |