# Showing data into a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

My data is taking shape now. however I, am struggling to show the data in single row , I have used the group by and also used distinct on Branch but still unable to get the data into single row. I would like the data as shown on the second table. Note, as Barnet branch has two secretary its okay to have two rows for that branch. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
select Branch,Region,Treasure,Secretary,President,Role_Status 
from #branchhealth
group by Branch,Region,Treasure,Secretary,President,Role_Status
order by Branch
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the second picture why do you expect the Role_Status to be blank for the row with Secretary John?  Also, what do you expect to see if there was 2 Treasures?

Comment: Please stop posting images and post a text based data table.

Comment: Because there are two Secretary  roles in Barnet, As Mike is already mentioned once on the first row under treasurer, I would like to keep the second row blank to avoid duplication.

Comment: Why do you have a `GROUP BY` when you have no aggregation?

Comment: Why are working with the denormalised data from your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77912715/how-to-view-row-data-as-column-without-loosing-duplicate-raw-values) and not the normalised data?

Comment: Also, why is Andy the Secretary that works with everyone else and not John?

Comment: This fiddle might help us collaborate better https://dbfiddle.uk/NUojMPu0

Comment: your problem seem similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72228504/collapse-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-based-upon-a-break-condition

Comment: @ThomA probably he thinks it gets his closer to solution, while it actually doesn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option where we `UNPIVOT` your data, add a `dense_rank()` and then `PIVOT` for the final results

```
with cte as ( 
Select Branch
      ,B.*
      ,RN = dense_rank() over (partition by Branch,item order By Value)
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ('Treasure'   ,Treasure)
                     ,('Secretary'  ,Secretary)
                     ,('President'  ,President)
                     ,('Role_Status',Role_Status)
             ) B(Item,Value)
 Where Value is not null  -- or Value<>''  (not clear NULLS or empty strings)
)
Select Branch
      ,[Treasure]
      ,[Secretary]
      ,[President]
      ,[Role_Status]
 From  cte src
 Pivot (max(Value) for Item in ([Treasure],[Secretary],[President],[Role_Status]) ) pvt
```

**Results**

| Branch | Treasure | Secretary | President | Role_Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Barnet | Mike | Andy | Mark | Full |
| Barnet | NULL | John | NULL | NULL |

Comment: Thank you, this is something new to me, much appreciated you help, it does solves my issue